# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient, force traffic on the wire for localhost?

Tags: c#, json, rest, fiddler, servicestack

This ServiceStack client code works:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:32949/test");
var request = new MyRequest { ClassificationId = new ClassificationId (21300) };
var response = client.Post(request);
```

However, when observing the traffic in Fiddler, I see nothing. I would like to observe the traffic to get a better idea on how to build the required JSON request for other clients I have to write.

To make the above code work, I had to reference the assembly that has the service, and I am suspecting that ServiceStack is making some clever calls to avoid sending a HTTP request. Is this the case ?

Why am I not seeing any traffic in Fiddler, and how do I force it  ?

HTTP traffic to localhost endpoints via the browser is shown correctly.

Comment: out of interest what happens if you replace localhost with your ip address (lan) ? or say a hostname that resolves to 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 gives same result. A different hostname, but pointing to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file, gives me the traffic in Fiddler as desired. Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your hosts file, located at

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

and add the following entry

127.0.0.1   mymachine.com

then point your client to `mymachine.com` instead of `localhost`

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I went with. This works because the .NET framework does not send any local requests through proxies, but just defining another name for localhost, works. Fiddler actually documents this - here: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question here - commenter @wal pointed out the problem to me:

This has nothing to do with ServiceStack, and requests actually go over the http protocol. The problem was looping back to localhost did not send the traffic through fiddler. It is actually explained on the [Fiddler2 FAQ page](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic).

Answer (score 1):

The other trick is to replace your "localhost" uri with your machine name, and that should work out of the box with Fiddler.

`http://machinename:port/test`